# Git pull specify author

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a `repo` and have formed a team on `bitbucket`. We are deploying on a test server which we both have access to using the same username and password.

The repo looks like this `https://MyUsername@bitbucket.org/MyUsername/reponame.git` in my computer as I am the one who created it. However, a teammate deployed on the server and the remote looks like this `https://teamMate@bitbucket.org/MyUsername/reponame.git/`. When I try pulling while on the deployment server, it throws an error invalid password.

I have tried to change the remote but it keeps telling me that the remote is already in use.

How do I specify which author is pulling the commit?

Comment: Worth noting: "author" in Git refers to the name and email address recorded in a commit. When you run `git pull` you're really running `git fetch` followed by a second Git command. The `git fetch` step is the one that calls up the other Git (in this case at Bitbucket), and `git fetch` never creates a *new* commit so it's not interested in "author" information. The other Git at Bitbucket, however, *does* want you to prove that you should have access to the Git repository there. That's *user authentication*, rather than "authorship".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is not to set any sort of authorship (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507988/git-pull-specify-author#comment101491547_57507988)) but rather just to change the URL associated with a *remote name* like `origin`.

To do this from the command line, use `git remote set-url`.  For instance, if you're logged in to the deployment server—the one where you want to run `git pull`<sup>1</sup>—and you've navigated to the appropriate repository:

```
$ cd /path/to/repo
```

you can first view the `url` stored under the name `origin`:

```
$ git remote
origin
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ... [snip]
```

then *change* it to whatever new URL you want:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://MyUsername@bitbucket.org/MyUsername/reponame.git
```

Note, though, that when your teammate logs in to the deployment server (as himself) and navigates to this repository, now he'll attempt to present *his* credentials to the computer at Bitbucket, while asking them for *your* access to that Bitbucket Git repository.  So you've fixed it for *you* and in the process broken it for *him*.  He will then have to change the URL back to use his user name.

This sort of thing is why deployment servers should authenticate to web-hosting sites *as the deployment server itself*, and not as either you *or* your teammate.  See [Shripada's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57508315/1256452) and its links.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using ssh based git operations rather than using https as in your case. With ssh, you will need to setup appropriate ssh keys so that the git operations can take place without you requiring supplying authentication information.

Refer:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/enabling-ssh-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640358.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html